# Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use ES6 syntax. My code is like this,

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    import { googleClientID,googleClientSecret,mongoURI,cookieKey  } from './prod';
} else {
    import { googleClientID,googleClientSecret,mongoURI,cookieKey  } from './dev';
}

export { googleClientID,googleClientSecret,mongoURI,cookieKey  }
```

This is showing the following error.

```
[0] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[0] [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
[0] file:///C:/Projects/emaily/config/keys.js:2
[0]     import { googleClientID,googleClientSecret,mongoURI,cookieKey  } from './prod';
[0]            ^
[0]
[0] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
[0]     at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:145:18)
```

I am following the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). My syntax seems ok. What is the reason for an error like this?

I also tried `import * as keys from './prod';`. This gives me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'`

My node version is 14.15.4. I am using `"type": "module",` in package.json.

Comment: I think that if you rename the extension of your file to `.mjs` it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imports can only be at the very top level. They're hoisted (above all other non-`import` statements), and cannot be in blocks or conditionals.

You'll need something like

```
import * as prod from './prod';
import * as dev from './dev';

const obj = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? prod : dev;
const { googleClientID, googleClientSecret, mongoURI, cookieKey } = obj;

export { googleClientID, googleClientSecret, mongoURI, cookieKey }
```