# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' error in node js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

```
"node": "14.16.0",
"npm": "6.14.11"
```

I have 3 js files,

**dev.js**

```
const keys = {
    googleClientID: 'creds',
    googleClientSecret: 'creds',
    mongoURI: 'creds',
    cookieKey: 'creds'
}

export { keys };
```

**prod.js**

```
const pKeys = {
    googleClientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    googleClientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
    cookieKey: process.env.COOKIE_KEY
}

export { pkeys };
```

**key.js**

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    export { pKeys } from './prod.js'
} else{
    export { keys } from './dev.js';
}
```

when I do this i am getting this error:

```
file:///home/vaibhav/Documents/email-app/email-server/config/key.js:2
    export { pKeys } from './prod.js'
    ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

where am I going wrong? because according to this [doc by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) if you go down to examples and 'export from' I did the same thing.
Do let me know if I need to provide any other information, because i am not very strong at javascrpt.
Also inside *package.json* i have set:

```
"type": "module"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use export inside if statements in node.js, but the following code should do what you are trying to achieve:

```js
    import { keys as devKeys } from './dev.js';
    import { pKeys as prodKeys } from './prod.js';

    export const keys = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? null : devKeys;
    export const pKeys = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? prodKeys : null;
```

Comment: yes I have given the same solution.. I realised you cannot export anything from inside if else statement

Comment: Would appreciate it if you marked this answer as the solution in that case. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding, you are re-exporting the keys from key.js.

try this in key.js:

```
import { pKeys as importedPKeys } from './prod.js'; // I think you had a typo for pKeys in prod.js export
import { keys as importedKeys } from './dev.js';
export let keys;
export let pKeys;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
  pKeys = importedPKeys;
} else{
  keys = importedKeys;
}
```

Comment: i did and now getting this error  export { pKeys }; SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: which version of node are you using?

Answer (score 0):

okay so according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556972/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) what I have learnt is that you cannot export inside if else statement MAY BE, I AM NOT SURE. But the solution to my problem is there and it is done in a slightly different way.